# Copying all data into one sheet, problem looping VBA

Tags: excel, vba, copy

Hello I'm trying to copy over a set number of columns with whatever the last row is for each sheet. I got this code to work but it only works for one sheet and not all the sheets. I can't figure out how to make it loop through all sheets.

I've tried using a vba code

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub CombineDataFromAllSheets()

    Dim wksSrc As Worksheet, wksDst As Worksheet
    Dim rngSrc As Range, rngDst As Range
    Dim lngLastCol As Long, lngSrcLastRow As Long, lngDstLastRow As Long

    'Notes: "Src" is short for "Source", "Dst" is short for "Destination"

    'Set references Pup-front
    Set wksDst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import")
    lngDstLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksDst) '<~ defined below (and in Toolbelt)!
    lngLastCol = LastOccupiedColNum(wksDst) '<~ defined below (and in Toolbelt)!

    'Set the initial destination range
    Set rngDst = wksDst.Cells(2, 1)

    'Loop through all sheets
    For Each wksSrc In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        'Make sure we skip the "Import" destination sheet!
        If wksSrc.Name <> "Import" Then

            'Identify the last occupied row on this sheet
            lngSrcLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksSrc)

            'Store the source data then copy it to the destination range
            With wksSrc
                Set rngSrc = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lngSrcLastRow, 9))
                rngSrc.Copy Destination:=rngDst
            End With

            'Redefine the destination range now that new data has been added
            lngDstLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksDst)
            Set rngDst = wksDst.Cells(2, 1)

        End If

    Next wksSrc

End Sub

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'INPUT       : Sheet, the worksheet we'll search to find the last row
'OUTPUT      : Long, the last occupied row
'SPECIAL CASE: if Sheet is empty, return 1
Public Function LastOccupiedRowNum(Sheet As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim lng As Long
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet.Cells) <> 0 Then
        With Sheet
            lng = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                              After:=.Range("A1"), _
                              Lookat:=xlPart, _
                              LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                              SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                              SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                              MatchCase:=False).Row
        End With
    Else
        lng = 1
    End If
    LastOccupiedRowNum = lng
End Function

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'INPUT       : Sheet, the worksheet we'll search to find the last column
'OUTPUT      : Long, the last occupied column
'SPECIAL CASE: if Sheet is empty, return 1
Public Function LastOccupiedColNum(Sheet As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim lng As Long
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet.Cells) <> 0 Then
        With Sheet
            lng = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                              After:=.Range("A1"), _
                              Lookat:=xlPart, _
                              LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                              SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                              SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                              MatchCase:=False).Column
        End With
    Else
        lng = 1
    End If
    LastOccupiedColNum = lng
End Function
```

This code only does one sheet in the workbook and not all sheets

Comment: You get the value of `lngDstLastRow` but you do not use it in `Set rngDst = wksDst.Cells(2, 1)`.

Comment: @tonydallimore thank you! that made it work now.

Comment: @tonydallimore do you know what i need to do to change the code so it copy/pastes as a value?

Comment: @tonydallimore also how can i change the code to chose specific sheets and not all?

Comment: @scottcraner how are you

Comment: "Do you know what i need to do to change the code so it copy/pastes as a value?"  You will need to add one extra statement at the end which I will explain when you add some more detail.  You have a function `LastOccupiedColNum` but you do not use it.  You assume all the source worksheets have 9 columns.  Do all the source worksheets have the same columns?  If you have header rows, you are copying them all to the destination sheet.

Comment: "How can I change the code to chose specific sheets and not all?"  Suppose the worksheets are named A to Z.  Do you want to copy worksheets A, M and Z or all worksheets except A, M, Z and Import?

Comment: @tonydallimore on my spreadsheet there are multiple tabs 20+ I only want to copy the data from two sheets "Pro Rates" "Weekly Labor" these two sheets have the same exact 9 columns and I need to paste it as a value

Comment: @tonydallimore I got rid of the "LastOccupiedColNum" function

Answer (score 0):

In the code below, I have tried to stick to your naming conventions but have tackled the requirement in a slightly different way.

The source worksheet names are loaded to Variant `wksSrcNames`.  I then use a `For Each` loop to copy the data from each of the source worksheets.  I believe this is the easiest way of loading data from selected worksheets.

If I interpret your code correctly, you do not copy the header row of the source worksheet to the destination worksheet.  You just copy rows 2 to LastRow from the source worksheet.  I do the same but before copying any data rows, I copy the header row from the first source worksheet.

I planned to copy the data including the formulae as you do.  At the end of the routine, I would have:

```
  ' Copy data in wksDst over itself to convert formulae to values
  With wksDst
    Set rngDst = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lngDstNextRow - 1, lngLastCol)
  End With
  rngDst.Value = rngDst.Value
```

Copying the whole of worksheet “Import” to itself, converts all the formulae to values.  This technique might have worked for you but it did not work with my test data because I had included the function `Row()` in some of my formulae.  When I copied a row from the source worksheet to “Import” the value changed to reflect the row number in worksheet “Import”.  When I converted formulae to values, I froze the new value not the original value.

I now copy the data in two stages.  The first stage is the same as yours.  This moves any cell-level formatting.  I then copy the source values to a Variant and then copy the Variant to the destination range.  This converts the formulae to their original values.

I think you will find this code self-explanatory but ask questions if necessary:

```
Option Explicit

  ' You use literal 9 in your code for the number of columns.
  ' In six months or a year someone will add or remove a column.
  ' You will then have to search through your code for those 9s
  ' which identify the last column. You may be lucky and that
  ' is the only use of 9. If you had ever had to check code for
  ' a literal that was no longer correct, you would understand
  ' why I never use them. With a constant, change the constant
  ' and the code is fixed.

  ' Your code assumes one header row which is not copied to
  ' worksheet "Import".

  Const lngLastCol As Long = 9
  Const lngFirstDataRow As Long = 2
Public Sub CombineDataFromAllSheets()

  Dim wksSrc As Worksheet, wksDst As Worksheet
  Dim rngSrc As Range, rngDst As Range
  Dim lngSrcLastRow As Long, lngDstNextRow As Long
  Dim wksSrcNames As Variant, wksSrcName As Variant
  Dim CellValues As Variant

  'Notes: "Src" is short for "Source", "Dst" is short for "Destination"

  ' ThisWorkBook is the workbook containing the macro.  If you have
  ' multiple workbooks open, you have to be really careful to identify
  ' the correct workbook.  Sometimes you identify the workbook and
  ' sometimes you don't.  I have removed ThisWorkbook when you used it.

  'Set references Pup-front
  Set wksDst = Worksheets("Import")

  ' VBA.Array will set wksSrcNames to a zero-based array of worksheet
  ' names. To add another worksheet or change the sequence, just update
  ' this statement.
  wksSrcNames = VBA.Array("Pro Rates", "Weekly Labor")

  With wksDst
    ' Clear any previous data
    .Cells.EntireRow.Delete
  End With

  ' Copy the header rows , if any, from the first worksheet.
  ' I assume you have no formulae in your header row.
  If lngFirstDataRow > 1 Then
    Set wksSrc = Worksheets(wksSrcNames(0))
    With wksSrc
      Set rngSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lngFirstDataRow - 1, lngLastCol))
    End With
    lngDstNextRow = 1
    rngSrc.Copy Destination:=wksDst.Cells(lngDstNextRow, 1)
  End If

  ' Prepare lngDstNextRow for first set of data rows
  lngDstNextRow = lngFirstDataRow

   For Each wksSrcName In wksSrcNames

    Set wksSrc = Worksheets(wksSrcName)
    lngSrcLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksSrc)
    With wksSrc
      Set rngSrc = .Range(.Cells(lngFirstDataRow, 1), .Cells(lngSrcLastRow, lngLastCol))
    End With
    With wksDst
      Set rngDst = .Range(.Cells(lngDstNextRow, 1), _
                          .Cells(lngDstNextRow + rngSrc.Rows.Count - 1, lngLastCol))
    End With
    ' Copy values, formulae and formats
    rngSrc.Copy Destination:=wksDst.Cells(lngDstNextRow, 1)
    ' Copy values
    CellValues = rngSrc.Value
    rngDst.Value = CellValues
    ' Prepare lngDstNextRow for next set of data rows
    lngDstNextRow = lngDstNextRow + rngSrc.Rows.Count

  Next

  With wksDst
    .Columns.AutoFit  ' Set column widths so data fits
  End With

End Sub

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'INPUT       : Sheet, the worksheet we'll search to find the last row
'OUTPUT      : Long, the last occupied row
'SPECIAL CASE: if Sheet is empty, return 1
Public Function LastOccupiedRowNum(Sheet As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim lng As Long
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet.Cells) <> 0 Then
        With Sheet
            lng = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                              After:=.Range("A1"), _
                              Lookat:=xlPart, _
                              LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                              SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                              SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                              MatchCase:=False).Row
        End With
    Else
        lng = 1
    End If
    LastOccupiedRowNum = lng
End Function
```